# How to migration:run database typeorm in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I use `typeOrm` for my `Nestjs`.

I want to `migrate` to database.

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { CatsModule } from './cats/cats.module';
import QuestionModule from './questions/questions.module';
import { typeOrmConfig } from './database/type-orm.config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig),
    CatsModule,
    QuestionModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`type-orm.config.ts`:

```
import Question from './entity/question.entity';
import Tag from './entity/tag.entity';
import { Question1684487687296 } from './migration/1684487687296-Question';
import { Tag1684487944636 } from './migration/1684487944636-Tag';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

config();

export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  entities: [Question, Tag],
  migrations: [Question1684487687296, Tag1684487944636],
  synchronize: false,
};
```

Script to migrate:

```
"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs",
"migration": "npm run typeorm migration:run -- -d ./src/database/type-orm.config.ts",
"migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- -d ./src/database/type-orm.config.ts migration:revert"
```

When I run `npm run migration`: `Error: Given data source file must contain export of a DataSource instance`.

But there is no DataSource in `Nestjs`.

Answer (score 0):

Need a data-source file as below:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: process.env.DATABASE_TYPE,
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT
    ? parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT, 10)
    : 5432,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  synchronize: process.env.DATABASE_SYNCHRONIZE === 'true',
  dropSchema: false,
  keepConnectionAlive: true,
  logging: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: 'src',
    migrationsDir: 'src/database/migrations',
    subscribersDir: 'subscriber',
  },
  extra: {
    // based on https://node-postgres.com/api/pool
    // max connection pool size
    max: process.env.DATABASE_MAX_CONNECTIONS
      ? parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_MAX_CONNECTIONS, 10)
      : 100
  },
} as DataSourceOptions);
```

Run command

```
yarn typeorm --dataSource=src/common/database-mysql/data-source.ts migration:run
```